# Are there any length limitations for image alt or title property?

Tags: seo, html, alt-attribute, title-attribute

I'd like to insert an image on a webpage with an `alt` property. But the text length I'd like to use for this `alt` property is pretty long: about 200 words (slightly less than 1000 characters). Moreover this text has some line breaks.

I have some doubts that such a long `alt` property won't be appreciated by search engines. So do I need to follow some guidelines regarding the length of an `alt` property?

I have the same question regarding the `title` property.

Comment: "title attribute" or "title element"? They are two different things.

Comment: @w3d initially I asked about `title` 'property' (i.e. `<img href="image.jpg" title="image title goes here">`). But @dan twice edited 'property' to 'attribute and then to 'element'. And now I'm not sure which term is correct in this way.

Comment: The `title` _attribute_ is what can appear inside the `img` element (or _tag_). The `title` element, on the other hand, is the main title of your page that goes in the `head` section. (You seem to have answered this in comments below.)

Comment: @RomanMatveev I updated my answer for both, since title _property_ could refer to either.

Comment: I edited the question back to use the OP's original term _property_ (which will unfortunately be less clear to others now).

Comment: @dan: You didn't need to change it back. Property is synonymous with attribute in this instance - attribute is the correct term - property is often used to refer to the equivalent JavaScript "property" (the two are often the same). But you had changed the very last instance of "property" to "element" - which has a very different meaning and introduced the ambiguity.

Comment: @w3d Let's let the OP change it to whatever they had meant to ask about...kind of getting sorry I even tried to answer it in the first place ;-)

Comment: @dan: cough, attributes, cough cough ;) No worries mate - don't be sorry, you've got a great answer and answers both - two for the price of one! (+1) :)

Comment: @w3d Thanks, I do my best to try to understand/interpret questions, and go out on limb sometimes in the process... Thanks for the editorial review, two eyes/minds are always better than one :-)

Comment: @w3d, @dan, Now I'm really confused with the terminology... The only thing is really clear now is that term *element* refers to a tag (i.e. `<title>`). But which term is correct for the *data* within a tag (i.e. `src`, `href`, `title`, `width`...)? I used to see both in docs available in the Internets...

Comment: @RomanMatveev: `src`, `href`, etc. (data within a tag) are HTML _attributes_.

Comment: @w3d So what is the term `property` mean?

Comment: @RomanMatveev: In HTML, the term "property" is not defined. However, in the parsed document tree (DOM) which you access via script, element nodes are objects that contain "properties". Many of these properties map directly to HTML attributes - this is probably where the confusion comes from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So do I need to follow some guidelines regarding the length of an *alt*
>   property?

There is no set *maximum* length for the value of `alt` tags, however, most advise for the benefit of sight impaired users to keep it under 125 characters - see [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/SKte6B1VvYU) and [this](http://accessibility.psu.edu/imageshtml).

> I have the same question regarding the *title* property.

In regards to title *attributes*, like with the `alt` text, there is no set *maximum* length. However, since this is used for [tooltip text for an element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp), usability for the visually impaired should also be considered as the W3 covers [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H33), suggesting that the 125 character size would similar apply. You may also find through browser compatibility testing, that the tooltip will get cutoff after a certain length, varying by browser.

Since title *property* might also refer to title *element*, search engines like Google will truncate your title *element*, or even compose their own based on your content, if it's too long. As suggested here by [MOZ](http://moz.com/learn/seo/title-tag), the goal should be to keep it to under 70 characters or less:

> **Title Tag: Best Practices for Length**
>
> Aim for title tags containing fewer than 70 characters. This is the
>   limit Google displays in search results. Title tags longer than 70
>   characters may be truncated in the results, or search engines may
>   choose to display different text from the document in place of the
>   title tag. Recent experiments have shown that the number of characters
>   displayed in the search results may also vary based on—among other
>   things—the width in pixels of each letter. 70 characters is still a
>   good general guideline for length, though.

Answer (score 2):

The alt attribute's SEO value is minimal to begin with. You can also be sure that, like page titles, anchor text, etc, at some point search engines stop reading that content and/or devalue it.

Alt attributes are supposed to be short and descriptive so it sounds like you are misusing that attribute. You probably should be using the [longdesc](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-longdesc/) attribute instead which allows for more verbose content.

Comment: Is that correct that `alt` attr is NOT very important for SEO purposes? I supposed otherwise  before... Is `longdesc` taking into account by SE's?

Comment: Alt is extremely important ;) great for accessibility and seo.

Comment: Would you say it is extremely important for SEO? I don' think that is the case.

Comment: Note that the `longdesc` attribute takes a URL, rather than direct textual content, like the `alt` attribute. But do any browsers (or search engines) actually support the `longdesc` attribute?